# Variable not expanding in zsh printf

Tags: shell, printf, zsh, variable-expansion

I'm trying to execute the following `printf` statement in a zsh script I'm working on:

```
printf "%s\n" "${CREATE_WS[@]}"
```

Where `$CREATE_WS` is an indexed array as follows:

```
CREATE_WS=("************************************************************************" \
        "You are about to create the $workspace workspace using the" \
        "version set $versionset. Do you want to continue?" \
        "************************************************************************" \
        " ")
```

Where `$workspace` and `$versionset` are taken from command line arguments. If I `echo` both variables by themselves, the console shows that they are non-null and have the string that was entered on the command line. However, when the `printf` statement runs, the variables do not expand into the strings that they contain as expected, and are printed as though they are null.

I've tried wrapping the variables in curly braces like so: `${versionset}`. But this also doesn't give me the desired behavior. What have I written wrong in this procedure, and how do I correct it?

Comment: Variables inside strings are expanded when you assign to `CREATE_WS`, not when you use it.

Comment: Were the `$workspace` and `$versionset` variables set when you executed the `CREATE_WS=` statement?

Comment: Good point. CREATE_WS is a constant that is set at runtime. Since that gets set PRIOR to the script processing command line arguments, those two variables aren't set yet at that point.

Comment: All variables are set at runtime. You just need to fix the order that they're set.

Comment: `${versionset}` and `$versionset` are *identical*; braces are the canonical "spelling" for a parameter expansion, but they can be dropped when doing so will not introduce an ambiguity or result in a different parse. (E.g., `${foo}bar` vs `$foobar`.)

Comment: The line continuations are unnecessary; the array assignment cannot end without closing the `)`, so the parser will not treat a newline as terminating the command.

Comment: @Barmar If I define `$versionset` and `$workspace` as empty variables at runtime, prior to defining $CREATE_WS, would that resolve the issue?

Comment: No, that will just put the empty values into `CREATE_WS`.

Comment: Variables aren't templates, they don't fill in placeholders when expanded.

Comment: It sounds like you should write a function, not use variables.

Comment: How would you suggest constructing the function? My goal was to centralize as much as my string variables as possible, to make them easier to edit in the future. Obviously, this issues poses a problem to accomplishing that goal.

Comment: Works for me, although it can be written simpler: Example code (for testing): `CREATE_WS=(a b c);  printf "%s\n" $CREATE_WS`. If you don't get the desired output, your array does not contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (note the single quotes):

```
create_ws_msg=(
  'workspace: $workspace'
  'version: $versionset'
  '***'
  '' )

workspace=ws21
versionset=3.14

print ${(eF)create_ws_msg}

# => workspace: ws21
# => version: 3.14
# => ***
# =>
```

The variable reference `${...}` in the print statement has two parameter expansion flags, in  parentheses.  `e` expands nested variables, and `F` adds newlines.   The `zshexpn` man page has details on these and other flags.

---

As noted in the comments, you could use a function instead.  That may prove easier for a future maintainer to understand, since zsh uses the same syntax as bash.

Using named variables:

```
function print_create_ws_msg {
  printf '%s\n' \
    "workspace: $workspace" \
    "version: $versionset" \
    '***'
}

workspace='ws42'
versionset='4.2'
print_create_ws_msg
```

Using positional parameters:

```
function print_create_ws_msg {
  printf '%s\n' \
    "workspace: $1" \
    "version: $2" \
    '***'
}

print_create_ws_msg 'wsa' '99'
```